# Android: Message Passing Between Two Devices Using Bluetooth (Two App or Same App)

Tags: android, push-notification, message-passing

I am conducting an android research study, where I will manipulate some variables from one Android App and the participant will get an update on their device. Sometimes, the receiver will get a push notification. I want to develop two apps: one for me ( let's say X) and another for the participant (Let's say Y). For example, I will open app X on my mobile and change a variable Z to 10. The participant will open app Y and can see the variable Z=10. If I set Z=100, then the participant will get a push notification that Z has changed to 100.

Is there any way to pass messages between two apps on two devices using Bluetooth? If not, can we send it by using the same app but two different interfaces?

If it cannot be done via Bluetooth, what are some other ways to do it?

Comment: Why bluetooth? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Data connection is not reliable all the time. As I will be nearby, I want to use Bluetooth.